# show that $(p \to q) \vee (p \to r) \to (q \vee r)$ and $p\vee q\vee r$ are logically equivalent

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

without using the truth table:

Show that

> $(p \to q) \vee (p \to r) \to (q \vee r)$ and $p\vee q\vee r$
>    are logically equivalent.

Comment: @tolly What do you try?

Comment: @Hassan Muhammad((p→q)∨(p→r))→(q∨r))≡ P∨q∨r

Comment: @tolly You have not make any effort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer...
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
(p\to q)\vee (p \to r)\to (q\vee r) & \equiv \neg [(\neg p\vee q)\vee (\neg p \vee r)]\vee  (q\vee r) \quad \text{by implication rule}\\
&\equiv \neg[(\neg p\vee( q\vee r)]\vee (q\vee r) \quad \text{by associative rule}\\
& \equiv [( p\wedge \neg( q\vee r)]\vee (q\vee r) \quad\text{by De Morgan's rule}\\
& \equiv( p\vee ( q\vee r))\wedge (\neg(q\vee r)\vee (q\vee r))\quad\text{by distributive rule}\\
& \equiv ( p\vee ( q\vee r))\wedge T\quad\text{by negation rule}\\
& \equiv ( p\vee ( q\vee r))\quad\text{by identity}\\
& \equiv  p\vee  q\vee r\quad\text{by associativity rule}\\
\end{split}
\end{equation*}